# How to apply use map in this instance?

Tags: haskell

I have a list of months and a string.  I want to check to see if any of the months are in the string.  I also have a function that takes searches a string for a word.  Do I have to rewrite that function or is this possible with some form of map?

```
fullMons = ["january", "febuary", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "september", "october", "november", "december"]

searchStrList :: String -> [String] -> Bool
searchStrList str strList = elem (map toLower str) $ convertToLower $ words strList
```

How can I utilize these functions to do something like this:

```
check :: String -> Bool 
check str = searchStrList "january" || searchStrList "febuary" || ...
```

Still just learning Haskell, so any other comments on my code is appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that `fullMons` isn't a function but a list, and `searchStrList` doesn't type; `words` takes a single strings, but you apply it to a list of strings.

I guess what you're trying to do is find whether the words of a string contain any of the month names in `fullMons`. Let's try and derive a solution step by step. The first thing we want to do is apply `words` to our input string; that gets us a list of strings.

```
words str :: [String]
```

Then we want to find out whether any of the elements of `words s` is a month name. There's a function `any`:

```
any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
```

So, our solution should look like

```
check str = any ??? (words str)
```

and all we have to do is figure out the `???`. The `elem` function lets us check whether an element in a list:

```
elem :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
```

In this case, the list should be the list of months, and the element we're searching for should be the word of the string. So, to fill in the blank:

```
check :: String -> Bool
check str = any (\word -> word `elem` fullMons) (words str)
```

(Note: `` foo `op` bar `` is just `op foo bar`; a lot of operators are designed to be written and read this way.)

We can make this simpler and more idiomatic by getting rid of the parameter:

```
check :: String -> Bool
check = any (\word -> word `elem` fullMons) . words
```

This means that we apply `words` to the input, and then apply `any (\word -> elem word fullMons)` to the result of `words`. You could simplify this further to:

```
check :: String -> Bool
check = any (`elem` fullMons) . words
```

(i.e., "do any of the elements of the `words` of our input appear in `fullMons`?")

but that isn't necessary.

I think the original solution you were trying to get at was to check each month name on the entire string in turn. To do this, we just need to flip the control structure a bit:

```
check :: String -> Bool
check str = any (\word -> word `elem` ws) fullMons
  where ws = words str
```

(i.e., "do any of the elements of `fullMons` appear in `words str`?")

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `any` function to check if a predicate is true for any member of a list.

Here I have used the `isInfixOf` function from `Data.List` to make the predicate:

```
check :: String -> Bool
check str = any (`isInfixOf` str) fullMons
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data Month = January | February | March | April |
             May | June | July | September | October | November | December
             deriving (Eq, Show)

months = [March, December, April]
april = April `elem` months
```

Use the types, and from there convert from those types to the string representation, as in:

```
show April
```

Comment: `Month` should derive `Enum`, `Ord` and `Bounded`, too. Then you can get all month e.g. by `enumFrom January`.